# How to print out texts in TableView as text data not image data to PDF?

Tags: image, pdf, printing, tableview, javafx-8

I'm developing the JavaFX application who displays a TableView and outputs a PDF file by using the JavaFX 8 PrintJob and Printer APIs.
The JDK version is 1.8.0.

I expected that all texts in the Scene are output as text data into the PDF file.
However, the result is that the texts are rendered as images not text data.
The requirement of my system is to store all texts as text data so that the user can select and copy them via PDF reader software (such as Adobe Reader).

The question is how I should modify the TabeView property in order to print the texts as text.
I don't want to put the Labels onto each cell in the TableView, but if there is no way to achieve my goal, I'll take this unsmart solution.

For the investigation purpose, I just created the small application as shown below.
The application includes two buttons ([Reload CSS] and [Print] button), one label and one TableView.

- [Reload CSS] button: It has been set for the convenience for the test. The tester does not need to re-start application after modifying the CSS file. Please just click this button when you check the behavior after CSS file is changed.
- [Print] button: When it is clicked, the print dialog will be shown, then please choose one PDF creating software as the printer such as CubePDF.

Only one thing I found is, when the '-fx-opacity' style of the TableView is set with the value smaller than 1.0 (such as 0.99) in CSS file, the label which locates outside the TableView (in my case, it shows "Person List") is output as text data.
The text "Person List" can be selected via the PDF reader software.
However, the whole TableView is rendered as one images.
I would appreciate if some smart solution is provided.

Main class: PrintApp.java

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Main class.
 */
public class PrintApp extends Application {
    /**
     * Start the application.
     * @param stage Stage object
     * @throws Exception Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("person_list.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML file: person_list.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.FxmlController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>

    <children>
        <!-- Reload the CSS file -->
        <!-- * User does not need to re-start the application after the CSS file is modified. -->
        <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="10.0" onAction="#reload" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Reload CSS" />

        <!-- Print the "printBoundsPane" pane -->
        <Button layoutX="120.0" layoutY="10.0" onAction="#print" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Print" />

        <!-- Target bounds which is printed out. -->
        <!-- * When the [Print] button is clicked, the print dialog will be displayed. -->
        <!--   Then, the following "Pane" will be printed out. -->
        <Pane fx:id="printBoundsPane" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="260.0">
            <children>
                <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" text="Person List" />

                <TableView fx:id="table" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="260.0" visible="true">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="familyNameColumn" prefWidth="120.0" text="Family Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="givenNameColumn" prefWidth="120.0" text="Given Name" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </children>
        </Pane>

    </children>
</Pane>
```

CSS file: style.css

```
/**
 * Root pane.
 */
#rootPane {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

/**
 * Actual bounds which is printed out.
 */
#printBoundsPane {
    -fx-border-color: darkgray;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}

/**
 * Whole TableView.
 */
.table-view {
    -fx-opacity: 0.99;
}
```

Controller class: FxmlController.java

```
package test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.print.PageLayout;
import javafx.print.PageOrientation;
import javafx.print.Paper;
import javafx.print.Printer;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

/**
 * FXML Controller class.
 */
public class FxmlController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Pane rootPane;
    @FXML private Pane printBoundsPane;
    @FXML private TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person, String> familyNameColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person, String> givenNameColumn;

    /**
     * Initialize the stage.
     * @param location FXML file location
     * @param resources resources
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Link the data with a column.
        this.familyNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("familyName"));
        this.givenNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("givenName"));

        // Add sample records to the TableView
        table.getItems().add(new Person("TEST1", "test1"));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("TEST2", "test2"));
    }

    /**
     * Event listener for [Reload CSS] button.
     * Reload the CSS file.
     * @throws java.net.MalformedURLException
     */
    public void reload() throws MalformedURLException {
        // Get the stylesheet list.
        ObservableList<String> styleSheets = this.rootPane.getStylesheets();

        // CSS file location.
        URL cssLocation = new URL(styleSheets.get(0));

        // Reset the CSS file.
        rootPane.getStylesheets().set(0, cssLocation.toExternalForm());
    }

    /**
     * Event listener for [Print] button.
     * Print out the pane which can be identified as "printBoundsPane".
     */
    public void print() {
        // Default printer object.
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();

        // Print page layout object.
        // * Set "LANDSCAPE" as the page orientation for the convenience for the test.
        //   If the output pdf has the text information, the output file is shown in a PORTRAIT mode.
        //   If not, it will be shown in a LANDSCAPE mode.
        PageLayout layout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);

        // Create a printer job.
        PrinterJob  job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        if (job != null) {
            // Set the job name.
            job.getJobSettings().setJobName("TestPrint");

            if (job.showPrintDialog(this.rootPane.getScene().getWindow())) {
                // Print out the specified pane.
                job.printPage(layout, this.printBoundsPane);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Print canceled.");
            }

            // Finish the print job.
            job.endJob();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The class for defining a person.
     */
    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty familyName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty givenName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        /**
         * Constructor.
         * @param _familyName Family name of the person.
         * @param _givenName Given name of the person.
         */
        Person(String _familyName, String _givenName) {
            this.familyName.set(_familyName);
            this.givenName.set(_givenName);
        }

        public StringProperty familyNameProperty() {return this.familyName;}
        public StringProperty givenNameProperty() {return this.givenName;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Sending a JavaFX node (`printBoundsPane`) to the printer probably isn't what you want to do at all here. The problem is that you are only going to render the node to the printer: so, for example, if some of the content in the table is scrolled out of view, that content will not be printed. You probably need to generate a PDF document programmatically, using a library such as [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) and iterating through all the table's items (even those not displayed). You can then use the `javax.print` API to create hard copy if needed.

Comment: James_D, thank you so much for the prompt response.

In fact, at the beginning of the project, the requirements of the system were:
1. Create the customers list table to show it to the system user.
2. Show the print preview to the system user.
3. Print out the customers list on papers.

However, at the end of phase of the project, the PDF output function was added to the requirements.

Now I understand it's better to use PDF creation library.
I'll consider using PdfBox library since there is a license issue if I integrate iText library into the system.

Comment: But there is still one strange behavior I can't totally understand as following.  

1. When the opacity of the TableView is set smaller than 1.0, the label outside the TableView is printed with text info.  
2. Otherwise, the label is rendered as image.
  
Could someone give me an idea why this phenomenon is observed?

Comment: FWIW, I don't see that with the code you provided: however the text is completely garbled on the setup I have....

Comment: @Shin I have exaclty the same problem, pdf print of a tableView results in a bitmap and very poor quality non copyable. The Text rendering outside seems to me that the columns (invisible) actually overlap the outside elements which is why they are also getting rendered as a bitmap